# Нужно переделать программу, так чтобы мы могли выбирать для каждого студента свое количество предметов. с++

Tags: c++, c++11, структуры, список, динамические-массивы

ВОТ САМО ЗАДАНИЕ

Ввести несколько структур "Зачетка студента" с полями:

Фамилия студента

Номер зачетки
  Размер стипендии

Массив структур "Предмет"

Структура "Предмет" имеет поля:

Фамилия преподавателя

Название предмета

Оценка

Написать программу, выполняющую следующие действия:

­   -устанавливает стипендии для всех студентов, которые учатся на 4 и 5
­

-сортирует структуры в порядке роста среднего балла (направление сортировки выбирается пользователем)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

 //Количество предметов в зачетке
  const int subjectsCountInRecordBook = 2;
 //Размер стипендии
   const int paymentValue = 2000;

   struct Subject
  {
      char SubjName[30];
      char SurnameTeacher[20];
      int Mark;
   };

    struct RecordBook
  {
      int Id;
      char SurnameStudent[30];
      Subject Subjects[subjectsCountInRecordBook];
      double Payment;
      double avgMark;
   };

   int main()
 {
       int studentsCount;
       cout << "Enter count of students: ";
       cin >> studentsCount;
       cout << endl;

//Создаем пустые зачетки по количеству стедентов
RecordBook *recordBooks = new RecordBook[studentsCount];

//Заполняем информацию о предметах во временный контейнер
Subject subjectsContainer[subjectsCountInRecordBook];

for (int i = 0; i < subjectsCountInRecordBook; i++)
     {
         cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " subject name: ";
         cin >> subjectsContainer[i].SubjName;

         cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << "Surname Teacher: ";
         cin >> subjectsContainer[i].SurnameTeacher;
         cout << endl;
    }

        //Начинаем заполнять зачетки для каждого студента
      for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++)
 {
    cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " student's lastname: ";
    cin >> recordBooks[i].SurnameStudent;

    cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " record book id: ";
    cin >> recordBooks[i].Id;

    //Сумма оценок по всем предметам в зачетке
    int sumMark = 0;
    //Нужно ли платить стипендию этому стедунту?
    bool needPayment = true;

    //Скопируем данные из контейнера в зачетку и впишем оценки по предметам
    for (int j = 0; j < subjectsCountInRecordBook; j++)
    {
        strcpy_s(recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SubjName, subjectsContainer[j].SubjName);
        strcpy_s(recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SurnameTeacher, subjectsContainer[j].SurnameTeacher);

        cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " student's mark of " << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SubjName << ": ";
        cin >> recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark;

        //Установим стипндии для тех кто учится на 4 и 5
        if (recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark < 4)
            needPayment = false;    

        //считаем и заполняем средний балл в зачетке        
        sumMark += recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark;
        recordBooks[i].avgMark = (double)sumMark / (double)subjectsCountInRecordBook;
    }

    if(needPayment == true)
        recordBooks[i].Payment = paymentValue;
    else
        recordBooks[i].Payment = 0;
}

//Выбор типа сортировки
int sort_type;
while (true)
{
    cout << "Choose sort type(0 for ascending; 1 for descending): ";
    cin >> sort_type;
    cout << endl;

    if (sort_type != 0 && sort_type != 1)
    {
        cout << "Unknown sort type." << endl;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

//===Сортировка зачеток===
for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < studentsCount - i - 1; j++)
    {
        RecordBook temp;
        if ((sort_type == 0 && recordBooks[j].avgMark > recordBooks[j + 1].avgMark) ||
            (sort_type == 1 && recordBooks[j].avgMark < recordBooks[j + 1].avgMark))
        {
            temp = recordBooks[j];
            recordBooks[j] = recordBooks[j + 1];
            recordBooks[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

//Выводим отсортированный массив зачеток на экран
cout << "=========Sorted=record=books=============" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++)
{
    cout << "Student Surname: " << recordBooks[i].SurnameStudent << endl;
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Avg Mark: " << recordBooks[i].avgMark << endl;
    cout << "Record book Id: " << recordBooks[i].Id << endl;
    cout << "Payment: " << recordBooks[i].Payment << endl;

    //Инфа по предметам
    cout << "Subjects info:";
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < subjectsCountInRecordBook; j++)
    {
        cout << "\tSubject:" << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SubjName << ", Teacher:" << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SurnameTeacher << ", Mark:" << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark << endl;
    }
    cout << "==================" << endl;
}

delete[] recordBooks;
system("pause");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: ВОТ САМО ЗАДАНИЕ 
     Ввести несколько структур "Зачетка студента" с полями:
      Фамилия студента
      Номер зачетки
      Размер стипендии
      Массив структур "Предмет"
     Структура "Предмет" имеет поля:
     Фамилия преподавателя
     Название предмета
     Оценка 
Написать программу, выполняющую следующие действия:
­ устанавливает стипендии для всех студентов, которые учатся на 4 и 5
­ сортирует структуры в порядке роста среднего балла (направление сортировки выбирается пользователем)

Comment: А проблема в чём ? В том что Вы не можете её переделать? Или вы  пытались и у Вас не получилось? Если пытались - с какими проблемами столкнулись ?

Comment: Я просто не могу ее переделать. Вроде бы нужно здесь использовать список, но я не очень хорошо понимаю как, не могли бы вы помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да тут особо и переделывать ничего не надо.

Добавляете ввод числа предметов (по аналогии с вводом числа студентов),
и не забываете выделить и почистить память за собой (по аналогии с массивом зачёток). Всё.

В примере вводится количество предметов для всех студентов. 
Если нужно чтобы количество предметов у студентов могло быть разным (у одного 2, у другого 4) - добавляете в структуру зачётки поле с количеством предметов, я для каждого студента вводите количество его предметов и сами предметы.

Ещё есть вариант когда у вас предметы фиксированы - 10 штук, но у каждого студента свои предметы (некоторое подмножество из множества исходных предметов). Тогда заводите для структуры предмета поле `id`, и при вводе студента просите указать количество предметов, а дальше для ввода каждого предмета просите id предмета и оценку по предмету.

Если есть возможность - всё это можно переписать с использованием классов и std::string, тогда вы сможете использовать списки и вектора из STL: `std::list` и `std::vector`, что упростит задачи по работе с памятью.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

 //Количество предметов в зачетке
  int subjectsCountInRecordBook = 0;
 //Размер стипендии
   const int paymentValue = 2000;

   struct Subject
  {
      char SubjName[30];
      char SurnameTeacher[20];
      int Mark;
   };

    struct RecordBook
  {
      int Id;
      char SurnameStudent[30];
      Subject* Subjects;
      double Payment;
      double avgMark;
   };

   int main()
 {
       int studentsCount;
       cout << "Enter count of students: ";
       cin >> studentsCount;
       cout << "Enter count of subject:";
       cin >> subjectsCountInRecordBook;
       cout << endl;


//Создаем пустые зачетки по количеству стедентов
RecordBook *recordBooks = new RecordBook[studentsCount];
//Выделяем память под предметы в зачётке
for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++){
    recordBooks[i].Subjects = new Subject[subjectsCountInRecordBook];
}

//Заполняем информацию о предметах во временный контейнер
Subject* subjectsContainer = new Subject[subjectsCountInRecordBook];

for (int i = 0; i < subjectsCountInRecordBook; i++)
     {
         cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " subject name: ";
         cin >> subjectsContainer[i].SubjName;

         cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << "Surname Teacher: ";
         cin >> subjectsContainer[i].SurnameTeacher;
         cout << endl;
    }

        //Начинаем заполнять зачетки для каждого студента
      for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++)
 {
    cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " student's lastname: ";
    cin >> recordBooks[i].SurnameStudent;

    cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " record book id: ";
    cin >> recordBooks[i].Id;

    //Сумма оценок по всем предметам в зачетке
    int sumMark = 0;
    //Нужно ли платить стипендию этому стедунту?
    bool needPayment = true;

    //Скопируем данные из контейнера в зачетку и впишем оценки по предметам
    for (int j = 0; j < subjectsCountInRecordBook; j++)
    {
        strcpy_s(recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SubjName, subjectsContainer[j].SubjName);
        strcpy_s(recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SurnameTeacher, subjectsContainer[j].SurnameTeacher);

        cout << "Enter" << (i + 1) << " student's mark of " << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SubjName << ": ";
        cin >> recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark;

        //Установим стипндии для тех кто учится на 4 и 5
        if (recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark < 4)
            needPayment = false;

        //считаем и заполняем средний балл в зачетке
        sumMark += recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark;
        recordBooks[i].avgMark = (double)sumMark / (double)subjectsCountInRecordBook;
    }

    if(needPayment == true)
        recordBooks[i].Payment = paymentValue;
    else
        recordBooks[i].Payment = 0;
}

//Выбор типа сортировки
int sort_type;
while (true)
{
    cout << "Choose sort type(0 for ascending; 1 for descending): ";
    cin >> sort_type;
    cout << endl;

    if (sort_type != 0 && sort_type != 1)
    {
        cout << "Unknown sort type." << endl;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

//===Сортировка зачеток===
for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < studentsCount - i - 1; j++)
    {
        RecordBook temp;
        if ((sort_type == 0 && recordBooks[j].avgMark > recordBooks[j + 1].avgMark) ||
            (sort_type == 1 && recordBooks[j].avgMark < recordBooks[j + 1].avgMark))
        {
            temp = recordBooks[j];
            recordBooks[j] = recordBooks[j + 1];
            recordBooks[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

//Выводим отсортированный массив зачеток на экран
cout << "=========Sorted=record=books=============" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++)
{
    cout << "Student Surname: " << recordBooks[i].SurnameStudent << endl;
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Avg Mark: " << recordBooks[i].avgMark << endl;
    cout << "Record book Id: " << recordBooks[i].Id << endl;
    cout << "Payment: " << recordBooks[i].Payment << endl;

    //Инфа по предметам
    cout << "Subjects info:";
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < subjectsCountInRecordBook; j++)
    {
        cout << "\tSubject:" << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SubjName << ", Teacher:" << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].SurnameTeacher << ", Mark:" << recordBooks[i].Subjects[j].Mark << endl;
    }
    cout << "==================" << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++){
    delete[] recordBooks[i].Subjects;
}
delete[] recordBooks;
delete[] subjectsContainer;
system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Вывод:

```
Enter count of students: 2
Enter count of subject:3
Enter1 subject name: OOP
Enter1Surname Teacher: Egorov

Enter2 subject name: AIG
Enter2Surname Teacher: Ivanova

Enter3 subject name: TOE
Enter3Surname Teacher: Karlova

Enter1 student's lastname: Petrov
Enter1 record book id: 1
Enter1 student's mark of OOP: 4
Enter1 student's mark of AIG: 5
Enter1 student's mark of TOE: 4
Enter2 student's lastname: Sidorov
Enter2 record book id: 2
Enter2 student's mark of OOP: 3
Enter2 student's mark of AIG: 5
Enter2 student's mark of TOE: 5
Choose sort type(0 for ascending; 1 for descending): 1

=========Sorted=record=books=============
Student Surname: Petrov
Avg Mark: 4.33
Record book Id: 1
Payment: 2000.00
Subjects info:
    Subject:OOP, Teacher:Egorov, Mark:4
    Subject:AIG, Teacher:Ivanova, Mark:5
    Subject:TOE, Teacher:Karlova, Mark:4
==================
Student Surname: Sidorov
Avg Mark: 4.33
Record book Id: 2
Payment: 0.00
Subjects info:
    Subject:OOP, Teacher:Egorov, Mark:3
    Subject:AIG, Teacher:Ivanova, Mark:5
    Subject:TOE, Teacher:Karlova, Mark:5
==================
```

Comment: В примере вводится количество предметов для всех студентов. "Если нужно чтобы количество предметов у студентов могло быть разным (у одного 2, у другого 4) - добавляете в структуру зачётки поле с количеством предметов, я для каждого студента вводите количество его предметов и сами предметы." вот мне нужно , чтобы так было, но что-то не получается

Comment: @АлинаГордеева ну да, пока у вас получается только вопросы задавать =) Напишите что конкретно не получается. Приведите пример кода - Вашего кода. Автор кода, прикреплённого к вопросу, без труда бы решил эту задачу. Даже если бы у него были проблемы с выделением динамических массивов - в моём ответе он бы подсмотрел как это делается.